# WPF ToggleButton with Checked + Pressed State

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

I have a ToggleButton, which has a label. When it gets checked the label text changes and becomes longer, and the FontSize gets smaller:

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="#FF0000"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ToggleButton {StaticResource MyToggleButtonStyle}" Click="ToggleButton_Click">
    <TextBlock x:Name="ToggleButtonLabel" Text="Some Text"/>
</ToggleButton>


private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ToggleButtonLabel.Text = ((ToggleButton)sender).IsChecked == false ? "Some Text" : "Some Longer Text";
}
```

The button also needs to have a Pressed state, in which the FontSize decreases relative to it's current FontSize. In other words, it should work like this:

**Normal:** Fontsize = 22

**Pressed:** Fontsize = 20

**Checked:** Fontsize = 17

**Checked + Pressed:** Fontsize = 15

I know I can easily use a trigger for IsPressed State but this will also change it for Checked + Pressed, which is not what I want:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
</Trigger>
```

So what is the simplest, cleanest way to add a fourth visual state to combine Checked + Pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that easily from multitriggers:

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="#FF0000" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed"  Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MyToggleButtonStyle}" Click="ToggleButton_Click">
    <TextBlock x:Name="ToggleButtonLabel" Text="Some Text" />
</ToggleButton>
```